Why can't we have a custom data cloud matching rule which consists of name match and birthday match?
Why can't we have a custom data cloud matching rule which consists of name match and birthday match?
Looks like we can't create a custom match rule in Data Cloud without including email or address. Is including email or address a required step to define a custom match rules?
